# OOP Javascript, attach click handler to button from constructor does not work as espected

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want create an handler 'click' from a Javascript class and attach it to a simple button.

I created a simple Javascript class :

```
// from ./myclass.js
class Myclass
{
    constructor()
    {
        $("input.showAlert").bind("click", this._showAlert());
    }
    _showAlert(e){
        alert("foo");
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Myclass
};
```

And from my main js file :

```
// from ./main.js
const { Myclass } = require("./myclass");
var faa = new Myclass();
```

But if I do that, when I load my page via a browser, the alert "foo" appears automatically. I don't understand why and I don't want the alert is displaying automatically, but only when I click on the button 'input.addButton'.

My (very) simple html file :

```
<input class="showAlert" />
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: this._showAlert()  <-- you are calling it and  setting what it returns to the event listener

Comment: `.bind` has been deprecated for like 10 yrears, consider `.on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call your menthod here

`$("input.showAlert").bind("click", this._showAlert());`

Just pass the link to this method as:

`$("input.showAlert").bind("click", this._showAlert);`

Comment: thanks you ! that was stupid haha

Answer (score 1):

By writing `this._showAlert()` you immediately call the function, try `this._showAlert`